# Подскажите ошибку пожалуйста, не выполняется запрос при редактировании Php

Tags: php, html

Всем доброго дня. Может что заметит ошибку. Делаю редактирование статьи перехожу по ссылке редактирования дальше заполняю форму отправляю возвращает на главную но статья остается прежняя.

Вот код ссылки на форму

```
<main class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <h3 class="pb-4 mb-4 font-italic border-bottom"></h3>
            <?php include_once "./connect/connect.php";?>
            <?php
            if (isset($_GET['del'])){
                $id = ($_GET['del']);
                $query  = $connect -> query("DELETE FROM `articles` WHERE `articles`.`id` = '$id' ");
            }
            ?>
            <?php $query = $connect -> query("SELECT * FROM `articles` ORDER BY `pubdate` DESC");?>
            <?php
            while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)):
            ?>
            <div class="blog-post">
                <h2 class="blog-post-title"><?=$res['title'];?></h2>
                <p class="lead my-3"><p><?=$res['intro'];?></p>
                <p class="lead my-3"><p><?=mb_substr($res['text'], 0, 200, 'Utf-8') . '...'?></p>
                <p class="lead mb-0"><a href="/article.php?id=<?=$res['id']?>" class="text-black font-weight-bold">Продолжить чтение...</a></p><br>
                <?php if ($_COOKIE["log"] = $_COOKIE["log"]): ?> 
                <a href="?del=<?=$res['id'] ?>">Удалить</a>
                <a href="update.php?id=<?=$res['id']?>">Редактировать</a>
                <hr>
                <?php endif;?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            </div>
```

Вот сама форма

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once "./parts/header.php";
include_once "./connect/connect.php";



$id = $_GET['id'];

$query = $connect ->query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = '$id'");
$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);



?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Update</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form class="mt-4" action="code/update.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id['id']?>">
        <input type="text" name="title" value="<?=$res['title']?>" placeholder="Измените заголовок" class="form-control mt-2">
        <input type="text" name="intro" value="<?=$res['intro']?>" placeholder="Измените тему" class="form-control mt-2">
        <textarea name="text"  class="form-control mt-2" placeholder="Измените текст"><?=$res['text']?></textarea><br>
        <button type="submit">Редактировать</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот обработчик формы

```
<?php
require_once "../connect/connect.php";


$id = $_POST['id'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$intro = $_POST['intro'];
$text = $_POST['text'];


mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE `articles` SET `title` = '$title', `intro` = '$intro', `text` = '$text' WHERE `articles`.`id` = '$id'");


header('Location: /');
```

Ошибок не выдает, но не могу понять что не так. Спасибо

Comment: чтобы были ошибки, их надо включить

Comment: Включал, не было

Comment: Что значит "включал"? Ошибки должны быть включены вообще всегда.